# Validating dates with moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Why does the following output "false"?

```
var date = moment(["2014", "08", "31"]);
alert( date.isValid() );
```

I'm using [this](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js) version of the library

[the same code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petjaone/keLfh9o4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months are 0 relative. So you're trying to get August 31st, 2014. In reality though, you're getting September 31st, 2014. Which is not valid because September only has 30 days.

Try this...

```
var date = moment(["2014", "07", "31"]);
alert( date.isValid() );
```